# Official Protractor Tutorial not working when adding variables to top of spec file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to Protractor, & facing below issue.

I am able to run this basic spec file with no issues:

```
describe('Protractor baby steps', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    });

    it('should have a title', function () {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });
});
```

However, when I add a couple of variables to the top of the spec file, like below, I'm getting an error:

```
describe('Protractor baby steps', function () {
    var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
    var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
    var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton')).click();
    var latestResult = element(by.binding('latest'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    });
   
    it('should have a title', function () {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });
});
```

Here is the error message I'm receiving:

```
Failures:
1) Protractor baby steps should have a title
  Message:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
  Stack:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:461:23
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.<computed> [as click] (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.<computed> [as click] (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\ProtractorTutorial\spec1.js:5:47)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\ProtractorTutorial\spec1.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
  Message:
    Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
  Stack:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:461:23
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27
        at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    From: Task: Run it("should have a title") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
        at process.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at process.emit (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:439:21)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\ProtractorTutorial\spec1.js:12:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\ProtractorTutorial\spec1.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.145 seconds
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm following the official Protractor tutorials [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) so I'm not sure why it's throwing these failures.

Comment: I see you are declaring `goButton` with the `.click()` method at the end, try removing the `.click()` ? Other than that I don't see anything wrong

Comment: Yep that should work. 
Otherwise see if the wait for angular variable is set to true in your config file.

Comment: That was the issue alright, works fine once I removed `.click()` (I hadn't spotted that typo myslef). Thanks @JoaquinCasco